# Will closures in Java 8 enable factory methods using constructor pointers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, closures, lambda

My least favorite aspect of the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is the almost unavoidable necessity of lengthy **if/then** or **case** statements.  If you have many classes to resolve, it becomes even worse.  I just do not like lengthy if/thens.

Consider the following example:

```
public class StatementFactory 
{
    public static Statement createStatement(String stmtSql)
    {
        Statement rslt = null;

        String frstWord = stmtSql.split("\\s+")[0].toUpperCase();

        if(frstWord.equals("SELECT"))
        {
            rslt = new SelectStatement(stmtSql);
        }
        else if(frstWord.equals("UPDATE"))
        {
            rslt = new UpdateStatement(stmtSql);
        }
        else if(frstWord.equals("INSERT"))
        {
            rslt = new InsertStatement(stmtSql);
        }
        else if(frstWord.equals("DELETE"))
        {
            rslt = new DeleteStatement(stmtSql);
        }

        return rslt;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a static Map that maps **frstWord** to pointers of constructors of different **Statement** implementations so that I can just get the pointer from the map for a given **frstWord** and construct a new instance rather than have this if/then ugliness.  Of course, it can be done right now using reflection but it gets even uglier than the if/then.

My question is:  Can I expect [Closures in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/) to solve this issue for me and provide the above described desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
static Map<String, Function<String,Statement> map = new HashMap<>();
static
{
    map.put("SELECT", SelectStatement::new);
    // etc...
}

public static Statement createStatement(String stmtSql)
{
    ...
    return map.get(fstWord).apply(stmtSql);
}
```

Of course, you can do the similar thing in Java 7 with anonymous inner class, which is a little wordy.

---

For constructor reference `SelectStatement::new`, see section 9 of  http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html

Comment: is this currently supported?

Comment: yes you can download java 8 now and try it out. (though they are still improving on lambda supports)

Comment: no, but pre java 8 you can use an anonymous class instead of `SelectStatement::new`

Comment: `enum`s in Java SE 5-7 make it slightly less verbose.

Comment: using anonymous inner classes gets more messy than if/than, IMO.  closure is definitely the way to go

Comment: @foampile Or you can do this in java 7: `switch(fstWord){ case "SELECT" : return new SelectStatement(stmtSql); ... } `

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, can you please provide an example of how it can be done with `enum`?

Comment: @irreputable, `switch` is still not as elegant as the lambda solution you have in the answer above

Comment: @foampile `enum StatementFactory { SELECT { public SelectStatement createStatement(String sql) { return new SelectStatement(sql); }}, ... public abstract SelectStatement createStatement(String sql); }`

Comment: that's a bit messy.  definitely the closure is #1 and your switch from the answer below is my #2, in terms of elegance and coding style.  to each their own

Comment: for this particular problem, I would choose `switch`.

Comment: (By "slightly less verbose" above, I mean enums make it slightly less verbose than anonymous inner classes.)

Comment: If your cases are mutable at runtime, a switch is not appropriate.  A switch locks in cases at runtime.  A map allows new cases to be defined and applied at any time.

Answer (score 5):

Even in Java SE 7 you can write it as:

```
    switch (frstWord) {
        case "SELECT": return new SelectStatement(stmtSql);
        case "UPDATE": return new UpdateStatement(stmtSql);
        case "INSERT": return new InsertStatement(stmtSql);
        case "DELETE": return new DeleteStatement(stmtSql);
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

No need to get all hip about this sort of stuff.

Comment: not bad but i still prefer the closure way just a smidge better

Comment: @foampile They're called "lambdas" these days as they aren't really more closure-like than anonymous inner classes (although the `final`s can be implicit just for random difference). You really like all that indirection through a needless [when not needed] map?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without closures

```
interface StatementCreator<T> {
    T createStatement(String sql);
}

public class SelectStatementCreator implements StatementCreator<SelectStatement> {

    SelectStatement createStatement(String sql) {
        return new SelectStatement(sql);
    }
 }
```

similarly for the update, insert and delete statements. Then you map is created static or singleton or whatever...

```
static Map<String, StatementCreator<?>> factories = new HashMap<>();

static {
    factories.add("SELECT", new SelectStatementCreator());
}
```

Then pick up the creator and execute it

```
return map.get(frstWord).createStatement();
```

Ta Da!

Comment: It's slightly less verbose to use anonymous inner classes, or `enum`s.